# What does the second of these two Japanese symbols mean?

Tags: meaning, hiragana, punctuation

The first one is fine but I'm not sure about the second one? The first one is "na"  and the second one looks like "shi" on its side, facing down, but is it "shi" or something else?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean つ ([Tsu (kana) in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsu_(kana)))? It's one of the basic hiragana. なつ means "summer".

Comment: I don't think so. I tried to add a photo but it didn't work. It looks exactly like "shi" and I've come across it twice so I don't think it's just oddly written or anything.

Comment: Can you take a wider shot to see what comes before and after this word? Maybe from context someone can figure it out. It could be the small っ.

Comment: It's a manga and that's all there was in the speech bubble.